# How to resolve error "Error, disabling serialEvent() for COM14 null"?

Tags: java, arduino, processing, microcontroller, arduino-uno

I am using processing 2.2.1. Code I tried is below but it gives error "Error, disabling serialEvent() for COM14 null". I am designing thermometer which send data serially to computer. please help me I am new.

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial port;
String tempc="";
String tempf="";
String data="";
int index = 0;
PFont font;
void setup()
{
size(400,400);
port = new Serial(this, "COM14", 9600);
port.bufferUntil('.');
font = loadFont("AgencyFB-Bold-200.vlw");
textFont(font,200);
}

void draw()  
{
background(0,0,0);  
fill(46,209,2);
text(tempc,70,175);
fill(0,102,153);
text(tempf,70,370); 
}
void serialEvent (Serial port)
{
data = port.readStringUntil('.'); 
data = data.substring(0,data.length()-1);
index = data.indexOf(","); 
tempc = data.substring(0,index);
tempf = data.substring(index+1,data.length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your port **COM14** exists and is right:
`println(Serial.list());`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Darius' answer, look out for **Null** strings or any other potential parsing errors in `serialEvent()`.

You could try something like this:

```
void serialEvent (Serial port)
{
    data = port.readString('.'); 
    println("raw data"+data)
    try{
        data = data.substring(0,data.length()-1);
        index = data.indexOf(","); 
        tempc = data.substring(0,index);
        tempf = data.substring(index+1,data.length());
    }catch(Exception e){
        println("Error parsing:")
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Notice `readString()` is used since `bufferUntil()` is called in setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
// at the top of the program:
float xPos = 400; // horizontal position of the graph
float yPos = 300; // vertical position of the graph
float zPos = 300;
float regiypos = yPos;
float regizpos = zPos;
int par = 5;

import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;        // The serial port

int lf = 10;    // Linefeed in ASCII
String myString = null;
float num;  
void setup () {

  size(800, 600);        // (Width, Height) window size

  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM4", 115200);

  background(#081640);
  noLoop();                                                //-- Ne fussál folyamatosan

}

void draw () {
   // draw the line in a pretty color:
  stroke(#A8D9A7);
  line(xPos-par,regiypos, xPos, yPos);                        // (x1,y1,x2,y2) Origó a bal felső sarokban  
  regiypos = yPos;                                        // ami most új volt azt megőrzi, hogy legyen mivel összekötni

  stroke(#ff00A7);
  line(xPos-par,regizpos, xPos, zPos);         
  regizpos = zPos;

  // at the edge of the screen, go back to the beginning:
  if (xPos >= width) {
    xPos = 0;
    // clear the screen by resetting the background:
    background(#EDA430);
    background(#081640);
  }
  else {
    // increment the horizontal position for the next reading:
    xPos+=par;
  }
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {                      //-- Nem fut folyamatosan, hanem csak akkor ha adat érkezik, mert akkor meghívodik ez a fv.
  // get the byte:
//  float inByte = myPort.read();
  // print it:
//  println(inByte);
  myString = myPort.readStringUntil(lf);
  if (myString != null) {
      print(myString);  // Prints String
      String[] q = splitTokens(myString,":");
      if (q.length==2){
          print(q[0]);  // Acceltoroll print
          print(q[1]);  // Gyrotoroll print

          num=float(q[0]);  // Converts and prints float
          yPos = height/2 - num;
          num=float(q[1]);  // Converts and prints float
          zPos = height/2 - num;
          redraw();             //-- Melynek a végén van a redraw() parancs, mely egyszer lefutattaja a draw()-ban lévő részt.
      }
  }  
}
```

And the highlighted part is this:

```
if (q.length==2) {

          print(q[0]);  // Acceltoroll print
          print(q[1]);  // Gyrotoroll print

          num=float(q[0]);  // Converts and prints float
          yPos = height/2 - num;
          num=float(q[1]);  // Converts and prints float
          zPos = height/2 - num;
          redraw();             //-- Melynek a végén van a redraw() parancs, mely egyszer lefutattaja a draw()-ban lévő részt.
}
```

This will solve your problem. The problem is that q[1] may not exist if the buffer is full and begins to overwrite the data...